# Formatting multi-page PDF with large plots and LargeLabels on Landscape orientation

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format, pagelayout

I'm trying to create a multi-page [`"PDF"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDF.html) (application/pdf Adobe Acrobat format) file with code similar to this minimum working example code, featuring [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) and [`"LargeLabels"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html?q=PlotTheme#:%7E:text=italic%20serif%20font-,%22LargeLabels%22,-large%20sans%20font)

```
Export["Test.PDF",
    CreateDocument[
        ExpressionCell[
            #
            , PageBreakBelow -> True
            , WindowSize->All
        ]& /@ Table[
            ListPlot[
                Sort/@RandomReal[1,{5,20}]
                , Joined -> True
                , PlotLegends -> RandomWord[5]
                , PlotTheme -> {"Scientific","LargeLabels"}
                , PlotLabel -> RandomWord[]
                , ImageSize-> 600
            ]
            ,{5}
        ]
    ]
    , "PDF"
]
```

The image shows the problem: Legends are clipped and the page is portrait instead of Landscape.

[image]

I'm struggling to find a good way to programmatically avoid [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) being clipped, other than changing [`ImageSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) by trial and error. As pages are created programmatically, checking all by hand is undesirable.

Also, I can't find out how to define the correct page orientation, i.e to force a *Landscape* page if [`AspectRatio`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) $< 1$ and *Portrait* otherwise.

**How can one create a multi-page PDF file with the correct page orientation and avoid clipping `PlotLegends`?**

Comment: I guess, the problem is in the determination of correct width of the plots. The `ImageSize->600` is 600 printer points but it does not correlate with screen resolution and visible size of the plots..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the years of the site's existence, questions have regularly arisen about the export of multi-page PDF files, similar to this one, and for all this time an adequate solution without an involvement of third-party utilities has not been found. To my knowledge, using third party utilities is the only workable approach so far. It consists of two stages:

1. Export each page as a separate PDF file.
2. Merge all exported pages into one document using one of the third party utilities. I [recommend PyMuPdf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262512/280). Alternatively, one can use `pdfunite` from Poppler utils as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262494/280).

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyPopkov, you seem to be correct about this. Not the answer I was expecting, but I think likely the only good answer one can expect.